# Webpage Closedown - Warning - Page not saved

Tags: javascript, warnings, shutdown

I have an html5 application. It sends stuff to a database. Originally I was doing the database update instantly, however, now I am allowing for offline usage, and instead letting the user choose when to send to the database. (Eg if they are on a plane, they might want to do it later.)

So, now the problem is, if they shutdown, I want to warn them *before they do*, if they have failed to send any unsent data and allow them to return to send it if necessary. I will ultimately be using local storage until it is sent, so it wont be lost, but the important thing is to let the user know it is as yet unsent.

I will have a global g_bUnsentData = true; if there is unsent data.

Can this be done in javascript, and how can you do it?

Also, as an aside, how do I test for online status, so I can warn the user if they are offline and trying to send data?

Comment: You could use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) to test online status...

Comment: And you could try using the [Notifications API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/).

Comment: I recommend you to show a really visible label somewhere, to let the user know, that the data are unsent. That's IMO your best bet. Stopping window from closing, is in effect stopping user from closing browser. I only saw that when browser asks for closing more windows, and I always turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @SmartK8's comment.

Nonetheless, if you bind a function to the `beforeunload` event that returns a string, most browsers will display that string and a confirmation to leave the page. For example:

[image: The leave page confirmation on Chrome/Mac]

Some browsers might not display your returned string in the confirmation at all. Other browsers, especially mobile ones, will not even prevent the page from being navigated away from.

For testing the online status, `navigator.onLine` is a boolean value indicating network availability. It's not available everywhere (Opera, Firefox), but it's a start. See [this page at html5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks everyone. These are really helpful answers.